# Paypal sandbox unable to access my accounts, transactions, etc

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a sandbox account, and I can use my credentials in my app and test the payments.

But when I log in into the developer.paypal.com site, I cannot see my credentials, nor my sandbox test accounts, list of transactions, nothing.

I cannot create new accounts or credentials or apps.

On each page it says

> We’re sorry, but something went wrong while getting your credentials.
>   Please try again.

When fetching the transactions

> We’re sorry, something went wrong while fetching sandbox transactions.
>   Please try again.

If I try to create a new test account

> We’re sorry, something went wrong during account creation. Please try
>   again.